Chat.stackexchange.com chatrooms are broken/flaky
Chat.stackexchange.com seems broken. When entering a chatroom, the loading page stalls, e.g.

And transcripts don't load, instead I get a server error.
Some hints:

this only happens on chat.SE, not chat.SO or chat.MSE
I first saw this issue at 8:13 PM UTC (April 7), right after successfully posting a message in one of the chatrooms. The issue briefly went away at 8:32 PM but then came back at 8:35. I assume it will keep coming on and off.
I don't think this is related to this post and its dupes, because other people (contacted on chat.MSE) reported seeing the same issues, and I'm unaware of any account shenanigans of my own. And the issue is intermittent. And the chat main page loads fine.


Yep, repro here: Brave (Chrome-based), Windows 10 pro. Just started a few hours ago. In my case I'm referring to Chat.SE too.

I can see the exceptions on our side. It's nothing I have direct control over, but I have let the SRE team know.

Also repro on MacOS Big Sur, on Chrome. Anything on Chat.SE stays on the loading screen for sections of 2-3 minutes before briefly loading messages, then it's back to the square screen.

Although I'm pretty sure this is all server-side, but for the record I see the issue on both Firefox on debian linux and Opera Mobile (Chromium) on android.

Just to note, Charcoal HQ is down as a result.

FWIW someone in a discord server said "I sent 4 million As and now everything's 500ing" ¯\(ツ)/¯ could have something to do with it

@AaronBertrand if this is true y'all probably want to know about it.

@AaronBertrand for reference, the millions A message was sent in The Edge of Propinquity

As the person who sent the 4 million As: char limit doesn't apply to multiline messages, usually messages longer than 500 chars get shortened on the frontend with a (view full message), but for some reason this didn't happen here, which is probably part of the problem. here's the message. the chatroom in which it was sent still won't load for me, but the transcript appears to work.

Charcoal is working for me again now

can confirm its creaky

Wouldn't be surprised if  the message length check was client side and whoever did it skipped doing it client side.

@JourneymanGeek I'm pretty sure it's server side, but all I did was paste the message in the box and send it, expecting it to be displayed on my end as limited to 500 chars

@Ausername Why would you expect it to be limited? The (view full message) works, so the chars must get stored and retrieved.

FWIW, I frequently post query URLs longer than 500 chars in chat.

I'm fairly curious about exactly how this happened; we've tried sending enormous messages before and anything over four megabytes or so was silently rejected by the server.

Also please don't break main chat. There's many critical things that rely on it, and if something's fundamentally broken, I'm worried SO inc would rather sunset it than fix it.

@Ausername The problem was that you didn't send a multi-line message (a message with multiple lines of text separated by newlines). You sent a reply that started with a newline and the message had no other newline characters. When a chat message like that is sent, the chat system treats the reply as a "long reply". The entire message is displayed in the client and Markdown formatting is used throughout the message. Here's an example in the Sandbox where I was trying to see if I could get a newline-like look within such a message.

As of 03.50 BST, seems to have resolved.
